# How to record video from peerconnection_client-based webrtc client?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, rtp, video-recording, libjingle

How to record video from peerconnection_client-based (libjingle) webrtc client?

What I have tried so far:

Saving RTP dump using StartRtpDump: http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/viertp_rtcp

But I cannot play the dump back... Please see details [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/hJ-sOXl3z6M).

Any other suggestions how to play back this RTP dump, or how to record/re-stream video in some other way?